# Many to many relationship in ddd

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have two Aggregate root, Publisher and Campaign:

- 1 campaign can have multiple publisher registered,
- 1 publisher can have assigned to multiple campaign.

that means MToM relationship

so in Publisher class, i created

```
List<Campaign> _campaigns;
```

and in Campaign class

```
List<Publisher> _publishers;
```

I have created table with columns (id, publisherID,CampaignID)

But i have heard that MtoM should be avoided, how can i do that ? Do above depiction is correct ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932791/alternatives-to-many-to-many-relationships-with-cqrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true you should avoid many-to-may relationsships, because of the complexity that typically follows such associations. One way to do this is to enforce a traversal direction. So in your domain, if the most common operations is against a publisher and it's campaigns, you could argument that the bidirectional relation is only needed in special cases, and instead have a method on your campaign repository which retrieves all publishers for a given campaign. Then you could remove the list of publishers from your campaign class

Or of course the other way around.